# Hashicorp Waypoint Getting Timedout in local K3S

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I was trying to us Waypoint to install its `entrypoint` https://www.waypointproject.io/docs/server/run

But it seems to just hang indefinitely until it times. It's supposed to automatically bootstrap its context for the CLI by doing the install.

I'm running this under WSL 2 in Windows 10 Pro, with kubernetes k3s version:

```
Client Version: v1.19.3
Server Version: v1.19.3+k3s3
```

This is the result after I ran `waypoint install -accept-tos`:

```
✓ Creating Kubernetes resources...
✓ Creating Kubernetes resources...
✓ Creating Kubernetes resources...
✓ Creating Kubernetes resources...
 │ service/waypoint created
 │ statefulset.apps/waypoint-server created
✓ Kubernetes StatefulSet reporting ready
❌ Waiting for Kubernetes service to become ready..
! Error waiting for service ready: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Any guidance on this would be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: what happens if you try `waypoint install --platform=kubernetes -accept-tos` instead?  also, if you do `kubectl get all`, what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

If you ran into this with minikube here is my solution

`waypoint` service uses a `loadBalancer` type so you need to expose them

so run `minikube tunnel` in separate terminal (sometimes root  password needed) before you run  `waypoint install --platform=kubernete`